# Multiple conditions with Conditional Formatting

Tags: vb.net, excel, conditional-formatting

I have been working on VBA for use in Excel that can be used by my coworkers to help with checking-in product inventory from a delivery.  So far I have been able to figure out how to code to get all of the results I want so far but have hit a snag.

When coding to drop a series of Conditional Formatting conditions an error is thrown after successfully formatting the first cell in the column with the first of the three conditions.  The goal is to have the VBA pre-format all of the cells in a single column that we expect to use before we start adding content to the cells.

The code so far in case there is some other item causing the problem:

```
    Sub PopulateReceivingWorksheet()

    ''Step 1: Remove the first empty line from UNFI's text report of an invoice
        ''If Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
        ''    Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Rows(1).Delete
        ''End If
            ''Step 1 probably not needed.  Commented out just in case.

    ''Step 2: Use the LN column from the UNFI Invoice Report to calculate the number of rows
    ''to move to the Receiving Worksheet worksheet.

Dim lastUsedRow As Integer

lastUsedRow = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

    ''Step 3: Using the contents of variable lastUsedRow to tell Do..While.. loop to end.

Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(1, 10) = "Qty Received"
    Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(1, 11) = "Notes"


            ''Clear old Conditional Formatting in Column 10.  This should be QtyReceived.
    Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(i, 10)).FormatConditions.Delete


    Do While i < (lastUsedRow + 1)

        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 1) ''Cell i from Column A
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 2) ''Cell i from Column B
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 3) ''Cell i from Column C
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 4) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 4) ''Cell i from Column D
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 5) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 5) ''Cell i from Column E
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 6) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 6) ''Cell i from Column F
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 7) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 7) ''Cell i from Column G
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 8) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 8) ''Cell i from Column H
        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i, 9) = Worksheets("Paste Invoice Here").Cells(i, 9) ''Cell i from Column I

        With Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i + 1, 10)
            .Activate
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C2 = $J2"
                .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C2 > $J2"
                .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR($C2-$J2 < 1, $C2 < $J2)"
                .FormatConditions(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End With

        Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells(i + 1, 11).Formula = "=IF($C2=0,""Out of Stock"",IF($C2-$J2<0,CONCATENATE(-($C2-$J2),"" extra prodct received.  Check scope tags.""),IF($C2>$J2,CONCATENATE($C2-$J2,"" products unaccounted for.""),IF($C2=$J2,""All products received."",))))" ''Adds the If statement to each row in column, matching the number of rows from Paste Invoice Here worksheet.

            i = i + 1 ''Increases the value in the increment variable by 1 for each time the Loop is completed.

    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you need to place `FormatConditions.Delete` statement inside your `Do while... Loop` ...?

Comment: Unsure, I can try it.  I think the only reason I added the .Delete statement near the beginning is that I was getting an error when I had only a single conditional statement being applied with the FormatContions.xxx statement and the macro was run more than once on an already populated worksheet.

Comment: You are clearing Conditional Formatting in only Row 1 in Column 10. If you have intended to clearing it in all the rows than you should place that line inside `Do While... Loop`.

Comment: In the second line that is adding a conditional format, your formula shows "=$C2 > $J$". Should that not be $J2?

Comment: @ Zack.  Thanks for the catch.  It has been corrected but now the third conditional is throwing an error.

Comment: @ Nelly.  Are you saying that the .Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(i, 10) portion of the FormatConditions.Delete will not effectively clear out the entire column of any conditional format before the Loop starts or is it better coding etiquette to have the .Delete worked into the Loop?

Comment: Okay.  So far it looks like Zack's catch stopped throwing Error messages.  I guess the third conditional causing an error was a glitch or something.  Repeated runs of the macro work fine for the first use of the macro but will throw an error after a second consecutive run (Run Time Error 1004: Application defined or object defined error).  Though I just caught some logic error that I'll need to work through.  Thanks everybody =)

Answer (score 0):

There was an error on the second conditional statement's formula that Zack found.

=$C2 > $J$

Should have been =$C2 > $J2

Basically I missed a silly mistake ;)